# Design question in Python: should this be one generic function or two specific ones?

Tags: python, oop

I'm creating a basic database utility class in Python. I'm refactoring an old module into a class. I'm now working on an `executeQuery()` function, and I'm unsure of whether to keep the old design or change it. Here are the 2 options:

1. (The old design:) Have one generic `executeQuery` method that takes the query to execute and a boolean `commit` parameter that indicates whether to commit (insert, update, delete) or not (select), and determines with an if statement whether to commit or to select and return.
2. (This is the way I'm used to, but that might be because you can't have a function that sometimes returns something and sometimes doesn't in the languages I've worked with:) Have 2 functions, `executeQuery` and `executeUpdateQuery` (or something equivalent). `executeQuery` will execute a simple query and return a result set, while `executeUpdateQuery` will make changes to the DB (insert, update, delete) and return nothing.

Is it accepted to use the first way? It seems unclear to me, but maybe it's more Pythonistic...? Python is very flexible, maybe I should take advantage of this feature that can't really be accomplished in this way in more strict languages...

And a second part of this question, unrelated to the main idea - what is the best way to return query results in Python? Using which function to query the database, in what format...?

Comment: Unrelated to your main question, but if you are writing an interface to an SQL backend, you may want to try to follow the DBAPI as closely as you can: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/ -- DBAPI-compliant modules can be integrated more easily into other Python software that knows how to talk to databases.

Comment: `executeUpdate` could return the number of rows affected. For flexible result returning, you can pass a row_factory_function to your `executeQuery`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to answer the first part of your question, it seems like a matter of style more than anything else. Maybe you could invoke the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) to argue that it should be two separate functions.

When you're going to return a sequence of indeterminate length, it's best to use a [Generator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators).

Answer (score 4):

It's propably just me and my FP fetish, but I think a function executed solely for side effects is very different from a non-destructive function that fetches some data, and therefore have different names. Especially if the generic function would do something different depending on exactly that (the part on the `commit` parameter seems to imply that).

As for how to return results... I'm a huge fan of generators, but if the library you use for database connections returns a list anyway, you might as well pass this list on - a generator wouldn't buy you anything in this case. But if it allows you to iterate over the results (one at a time), seize the opportunity to save a lot of memory on larger queries.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have two methods, one which updates the database and one which doesn't.  Both could delegate to a common private method, if they share a lot of code.

By separating the two methods, it becomes clear to callers what the different semantics are between the two, makes documenting the different methods easier, and clarifies what return types to expect.  Since you can pull out shared code into private methods on the object, there's no worry about duplicating code.

As for returning query results, it'll depend on whether you're loading all the results from the database before returning, or returning a cursor object.  I'd be tempted to do something like the following:

```
with db.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM my_table') as results:
    for row in results:
        print row['col1'], row['col2']
```

... so the `executeQuery` method returns a `ContextManager` object (which cleans up any open connections, if needed), which also acts as a `Generator`.  And the results from the generator act as read-only `dict`s.